# Change bool status for all objects of all cells in the tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

Each cell in my tableView has various properties:

```
class: Item
// properties
    var name: String
    var photo: UIImage?
    var category: String
    var instructions: String
    var completed = false
```

(everything is initialized as well)

my tableView array is:

```
items = [Item]()
```

When Item.complete is true, the cell will have a checkmark accessory, else it'll have .none

I want to use a UIButton (in a separate VC) to make Item.complete = false for every cell in the tableView, thus removing all of the checkmarks and essentially resetting the data.

My items: Item array is variable, in that the user has the option to add or delete any row in the array.

I want the UIButton (located on a separate VC in a separate tab) to segue to the tableView and make the changes.

How can I change each cells .complete property to equal false with a UIButton so that I can remove the checkmark on every cell?

Comment: You have to iterate over the array and set the property of each item to `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `.map` function.

You cam run this directly in a Playground page:

```
class Item: NSObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var completed: Bool = false
}

// declare items array
var items = [Item]()

// fill with 20 Items, 
// setting .completed for every-other one to true
for n in 0...19 {
    let newItem = Item()
    newItem.name = "item-\(n)"
    newItem.completed = n % 2 == 0
    items.append(newItem)
}

// print out the items in the array
print("Original values")
for item in items {
    print(item.name, item.completed)
}
print()

// -- this is the .map function
// set .completed to false for every item in the array
items = items.map {
    (item: Item) -> Item in
    item.completed = false
    return item
}
// -- this is the .map function

// print out the items in the array
print("Modified values")
for item in items {
    print(item.name, item.completed)
}
```

and then, of course, call `.reloadData()` on your table.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function to execute a closure for each item of the array

```
items.forEach{ $0.completed = false }
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable

Comment: for index in items.indices {
                            items[index].completed = false
                        }

Answer (score 0):

Loop through items array and set property to false

```
for i in 0..<items.count {
    items[i].completed = false
}
```

Once done, reload your tableview:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

**Addition** if your question is how to do this from a separate VC, then I would suggest to learn delegation in Swift, here is a [post](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef)